# Visual Studio cannot open a designer for the file because the class within it does not inherit from a class that can be visually designed

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I've been working on a MySql Login and Signup form for around 6 hours now, but when I was coding it, for some reason the Designer kept showing in my code project. So I went to delete it not knowing the outcomes of it. Please help me out with this!

[image: Error]

Comment: See if this helps: [Cannot Display Inherited Form in Form Designer When Base Form Defined in 64-bit Assembly](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967050/cannot-display-inherited-form-in-form-designer-when-base-form-defined-in-64-bit-assembly)

Comment: Did you delete the file or the designer code in the file? I can see a tab at the top which suggests the code. If this is the case, can you not undo (Ctrl+Z)? If not then I think you would have to create a new form.